# Interpolate two VBOs in WebGL

Tags: webgl, shader, interpolation, vbo

I have two vertex buffers, each storing a sequence of XYZ coordinates in each element. How do I pass both buffers to the shader to perform linear interpolation between the coordinates of each buffer?

For example:

```
buffer1 = [3, 5, 7, 4, 2, 3 ...etc]
buffer2 = [7, 11, 3, 10, 0, 5 ...etc]
```

The resultant vertex buffer to be displayed to the canvas should be:

```
bufferInterp = [5, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4 ...etc]
```

I am able to use a single vertex buffer as follows:

```
vertexPositionBuffer = vertexPositionBuffer1;
vertexIndexBuffer = vertexIndexBuffer;
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPositionBuffer[frameCount]);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, vertexPositionBuffer[0].itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

Note the two objects both share the same index buffer.

My vertex shader is defined as follows:

```
var vertexShaderSrc = "attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;\n"
          + "attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;\n"
          + "uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;\n"
          + "uniform mat4 uPMatrix;\n"
          + "varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;\n"
          + "void main(void) {\n"
          + "gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);\n"
          + "vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;\n"
          + "}";

var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSrc);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind both buffers, and do something like:

```
attribute vec3 a_b1;
attribute vec3 a_b2;

void main() {
    float k = ...;                          // interpolation factor
    vec3 pos = a_b1*(1-k) + a_b2*k;
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
}
```

EDIT:

For binding multiple buffers, see this [lesson](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=134) on "Learning webGL".
That tutorial uses color and position buffers, but you could use any buffers with any purpose that you name them for. Binding more than two buffers is also possible, following the similar code.

You should use multiple `gl.bindBuffer()` and according `gl.vertexAttribPointer()` functions beofre dispatching a draw call. Below code is not the exact code required for your application, it's just an example.

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer1);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.buffer1Att, buffer1.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer2);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.buffer2Att, buffer2.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numItems);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I want to achieve, however how do I bind both buffers?

Comment: Edited answer. It should be pretty obvious from the tutorial code what's the exact pathway to binding number of buffers and using them in your shader. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the extra information. You've been very helpful!